# React Native, MobX app, Android simulator get TypeError: Network request failed

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, fetch, mobx

I get the data with fetch from the API and after render it in FlatList of my React Native app with MobX state management. On IOS it works perfect, with out any troubles, but on Android the data is not rendering on the screen. And before i tried to do it with react hooks in functional component with out MobX. And the behavior was the same on IOS works, but on Android not. It means the problem is not in MobX. 
The flow is:

```
fetch request => loading spinner => render data on the screen
```

In android just spinner is loading and nothing is happening, just a clean screen, the data is not rendering. I get the error:

```
TypeError: Network request failed
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onerror (whatwg-fetch.js:504)
    at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (event-target.js:172)
    at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (XMLHttpRequest.js:580)
    at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (XMLHttpRequest.js:394)
    at XMLHttpRequest.js:507
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (EventEmitter.js:189)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (MessageQueue.js:366)
    at MessageQueue.js:106
    at MessageQueue.__guard (MessageQueue.js:314)
    at MessageQueue.callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue (MessageQueue.js:105)
```

Any ideas how to solve it?
[image]

**Mobx store:**

```
import { action, observable, runInAction } from 'mobx'

class DataStore {
  @observable data = null
  @observable error = false
  @observable fetchInterval = null
  @observable loading = false

  //*Make request to API
  @action.bound
  fetchInitData() {
    const response = fetch('https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTicker')
    return response
  }

  //*Parse data from API
  @action.bound
  jsonData(data) {
    const res = data.json()
    return res
  }

  //*Get objects key and push it to every object
  @action.bound
  mapObjects(obj) {
    const res = Object.keys(obj).map(key => {
      let newData = obj[key]
      newData.key = key
      return newData
    })
    return res
  }

  //*Main bound function that wrap all fetch flow function
  @action.bound
  async fetchData() {
    try {
      runInAction(() => {
        this.error = false
        this.loading = true
      })
      const response = await this.fetchInitData()
      const json = await this.jsonData(response)
      const map = await this.mapObjects(json)
      const run = await runInAction(() => {
        this.loading = false
        this.data = map
      })
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
      runInAction(() => {
        this.loading = false
        this.error = err
      })
    }
  }

  //*Call reset of MobX state
  @action.bound
  resetState() {
    runInAction(() => {
      this.data = null
      this.fetchInterval = null
      this.error = false
      this.loading = true
    })
  }

  //*Call main fetch function with repeat every 5 seconds
  //*when the component is mounting
  @action.bound
  initInterval() {
    if (!this.fetchInterval) {
      this.fetchData()
      this.fetchInterval = setInterval(() => this.fetchData(), 5000)
    }
  }

  //*Call reset time interval & state
  //*when the component is unmounting
  @action.bound
  resetInterval() {
    if (this.fetchInterval) {
      clearTimeout(this.fetchInterval)
      this.resetState()
    }
  }
}

const store = new DataStore()
export default store
```

**Render component:**

```
class ChartsScreen extends Component {
  //*Component mount
  //*Call MobX store & setInterval
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.store.initInterval()
  }

  //*Component unmount
  //*Call reset MobX store & setInterval
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.props.store.resetInterval()
  }

  //*Change percent color
  percentColorHandler = number => {
    return number >= 0 ? true : false
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <NavigationEvents
          onWillFocus={() => this.props.store.initInterval()}
          onWillBlur={() => this.props.store.resetInterval()}
        />
        {Platform.OS === 'ios' && <ProjectStatusBar />}
        <IconsHeader
          dataError={this.props.store.error}
          header="Charts"
          leftIconName="ios-arrow-back"
          leftIconPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Welcome')}
        />
        <ChartsHeader />
        <ActivityIndicator
          animating={this.props.store.loading}
          color="#068485"
          style={{ top: HP('30%') }}
          size="small"
        />
        <FlatList
          data={this.props.store.data}
          keyExtractor={item => item.key}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <CryptoItem
              name={item.key}
              highBid={item.highestBid}
              lastBid={item.last}
              percent={item.percentChange}
              percentColor={this.percentColorHandler(item.percentChange)}
            />
          )}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to set Android platform code in the render section. As you can see in the render section you only set for IOS platform.

Comment: But its the render of Statusbar. How the render could be depends on it?